# how to compare numbers task

Tags: c, list, loops

So i got the following task in C : the user input two integers, let's call them n1 and n2, so that n1<=n2. 
The programm must print all the possible integers between n1 and n2 (n1 and n2 included),and that all the digits in the number are increasing in their value.
For example, if the user input 1234 and 1260, the programm will print 1236,1237,1238,1239, but not 1240, since 0 is smaller than 4.
Then it will print 1356,1357,1358,1359.

I'm not allowed to use arrays (otherwise it would be very easy), functions, even the power function. 
So I came up with the next pseudo code:

1. Make a loop that takes the number n1, and counts the number of digits it has.
2. Then make a loop that divides n1 (number of digits-1) times, and then with the remainder of the result of it, it will do % . 
   at this point you are left with some digit.
3. Then take n1 again, and divide it (number of digits-2) times, and then with the remainder of the result, it will do %. 
   at this point you are left with some another digit.
4. Compare the two digits. if first digit is smaller then the second digit, continue compairing digits by promotion of the digits location ( digitsNum--) .

   - do in loop steps 2-3-4.
   - if everything checks out, prints n1;
   - promote n1 (n1++), (up to n2)
   - loop everything again.

The problem is that with all the restricions on what I can use, I find my solution very hard to implement, and once I start, I just get one big mess .
Any suggestion on how can I improve it?

Comment: Show what you have done so far, even it is wrong.

Comment: What exactly are the restrictions?

Comment: Please show your research/debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: I think you are overthinking your steps - there seem to be way too many for this task. Checking if each successive digit in a decimal number is larger than the previous one is rather trivial. In particular, you do not need to know how many digits there are. All you need for that is % and /.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
        int num;;
        int num2;
        int flag=-1;
        int i=0,j=0;
        int rem,rem2;
        printf("Enter First Number\n");
        scanf("%d",&num);
        printf("Enter Second Number\n");
        scanf("%d",&num2);
        if(num>num2)
        {
                printf("Wrong inputs have given\n");
                exit(0);
        }
        int div=num2-num;
        for(i=0;i<=div;i++)
        {
                num2=(num+i);
                rem=(num2)%10;
                num2/=10;
                rem2=(num2)%10;
                if(rem>rem2)
                {
                        printf("....%d\n",num+i);
                }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank u so much! it makes a much more sense that my first attemp to understand the problem. altough i don't see the usage for j and flag variables

Comment: @Invader i modified my last program to write this. So forgot to remove j and flag variable.